# How can I use a system provided icon in Android (e.g. expander_ic_maximized)

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how can I use android's icon expander_ic_maximized?
I find that in frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/expanderic_minimized.9.png

Here is my layout xml file:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/expander_ic_minimized">
```

But I get this error:

```
res/layout/test.xml:70: error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'src' with value '@android:drawable/expander_ic_maximized').
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find all android icons in your android SDK installation directory. F.ex. `/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-16/data/res/drawable-hdpi/` on my computer. There are different sets of icons for different android versions and for different screen resolutions. Copy `expander_ic_minimized.png` files to your project `drawable` folders and the icon will become available.

According to android developer [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html):

> Because these resources can change between platform versions, you
>   should not reference these icons using the Android platform resource
>   IDs (i.e. menu icons under android.R.drawable). If you want to use any
>   icons or other internal drawable resources, you should store a local
>   copy of those icons or drawables in your application resources, then
>   reference the local copy from your application code. In that way, you
>   can maintain control over the appearance of your icons, even if the
>   system's copy changes.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b948576dbd33c209), you will have to manually copy that icon into your project and use it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just download and include it in your project

get it from [expander_ic_maximized.9.png](http://code.google.com/p/android-cookbook/source/browse/trunk/GroupHome/res/drawable/expander_ic_maximized.9.png?r=11) by clicking the View raw file link